# Issue Building C++ package with cmake: using Python .dylib, using 2.7 rather rather than 3.8, OS X

Tags: c++, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, cmake

I'm trying to build a C++ "Plug-in" that is part of "Orthanc" (Open Source Project).  I've been doing that on both UBUNTU and OS X, but I'm having trouble using a version of Python other than the system installed version (High Sierra, Python 2.7) on OS X.  I've tried installing Python 3.8 using the OS X package from the Python website and also using HomeBrew.  I'm not real familiar with compiling stuff of OS X, but a little better on UNIX.

The CMakeLists.txt file is fairly long, but the relevant parts are probably:

```
if (NOT ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Darwin")
  # The Python version cannot be controlled on OS X (yet)
  set(PYTHON_VERSION "3.6" CACHE STRING "Version of Python to be used")
endif()
```

---

```
if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Darwin")
  find_package(PythonLibs)
  if (NOT PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find the Python libraries")
  endif()

  message("Python library - Found version: ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING}")
  message("Python library - Path to include directory: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message("Python library - Shared library: ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
```

---

In the actual build there are a few lines of output about Python.  The CLI for the build is:

```
cmake -DPYTHON_VERSION=3.8 -DSTATIC_BUILD=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../
```

although I've tried various things for the 3.8, but it always defaults back to 2.7.

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.16")
```

---

```
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.16") 
Python library - Found version: 2.7.16
Python library - Path to include directory: /usr/include/python2.7
Python library - Shared library: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev):
  Policy CMP0042 is not set: MACOSX_RPATH is enabled by default.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0042" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:
```

My .bash_profile is probably messed up, but this is the most recent version.  I have installed both the 3.8 version using brew and the version from the .pkg on the Python website.

```
source ~/.profile
export NVM_DIR="/Users/sscotti/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

# The version installed with HomeBrew
# export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin:$PATH"

# The version installed with OS X installer
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"

 ##
 # Homebrew bash completion
 ##
 if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
   source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
 fi
```

Seems that maybe:

```
find_package(PythonLibs)
```

is not finding my other version of Python ?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Just getting started with Python, and it is a little confusing about how to set up a couple of different version of Python for development purposes.  I don't know if the brew or .pkg version of Python have the "dev packages" included.

Comment: Documentation for [FindPythonLibs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPythonLibs.html) module doesn't describe `PYTHON_VERSION`  variable as a possible way to affect the search. If you want to select specific Python installation, set `PYTHON_LIBRARY` and `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` variables accordingly. Also, the documentation says that the `FindPythonLibs` module is deprecated in favor to `FindPython` and some other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a follow up to my question.  I found that if I explicitly defined that paths for -DPYTHON_LIBRARY= and -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR in the cmake, then it compiles fine and I can use various versions of Python on OS X if I want.  I would imagine there is another more elegant way, but this works pretty well.

```
cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/ -DPYTHON_VERSION=3.8 -DSTATIC_BUILD=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../
```